# Downloading IOS Toolkits for Adobe XD using windows

Tags: file-format, ios, windows, adobe-xd

I'm trying to download the IOS toolkit for use in Adobe XD using a Windows Laptop. It'd downloaded as a .dog file and I have tried opening in 7zip but not sure which folder or file to choose from to go forward being there are a dozen or so. Any advice on another option to try?

Answer (score 0):

DMG is an apple-specific mountable volume file - can't open it on Windows, sorry.